# Yodlee - How I can identifying the itemAccountId for a specific account number

Tags: api, yodlee

As per the api description the  call : getItemSummaryForItem1 should be used to fetch the itemAccountIds for a site account. The response of this call has only last four digits of the account number. I need to identify which item summary corresponds to which account in the list of bank accounts under this site account. Is comparing the last 4 digits alone is sufficient?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not call getItemSummaryForItem1 to get itemAccountIds for a site account as Yodlee has enhanced the response of getItemSummariesForSite which now returns both itemID and itemAccountId hence you need not worry about any mapping.

Just to answer the last part - Yes the last 4 digits of the account number is enough.

Comment: thanks Shreyans, There is possibilities to have same numbers (last 4 digits) for more then one account right?

Comment: For the same user in the same bank? it should not be the case as Banks themselves do not allow that.